# C# streaming drone video

Tags: c#, video, tcp, ffmpeg

I am currently a student and I have a project which require using the drone and the livestream from its camera

I managed to find a control program http://www.winardrone.com which can control my ar drone 2.0 , but the problem is that the program doesn't support my drone's camera live stream method(TCP)due to the fact that the program is more compatible to the ar drone 1.0(older version drone) which uses(UDP)

so I have encountered a problem of putting the video stream into my program
,there are a really simple solution of using ffmpeg player with cmd command "ffplay tcp://192.168.1.1:5555", but it does mean that my program have to run in multiple windows and I won't be able to save my frames with my program to do analyzation

so could anyone tell me how to Stream my TCP video in my visual studio C# program and capture frames at the same time ?
just like the program in this video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4V5B-DPWdOQ

I wish to get the video image in a program instead of opening a new window

And sorry for my bad grammar, thanks for your reply